# How to add a line break if a specific text pattern is found

Tags: regex, editor, text-editor

I am looking for a tool (an editor), or macro that i can split the text something like this

```
AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDDD,EEEE,FFFFF
```

into

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDDD
EEEE
FFFFF
```

Comment: Anything that can replace a comma with your favorite flavor of newline would work.  I'm not a Unix guru but isn't there a command that will do this?

Comment: Thanks, I am not looking for unix solution, a windows solution is fine too. But comma is just an example, it could be anything. I agree with your solution, but in an editor how do you replace a comma with newline (/n/r).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Notepad++. These should be the steps:

1. Press ctrl-H
2. On Find what: ,
3. On Replace with: \n
4. On search mode: extended

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sublime Text 2.  You have to press the button that "turns on" regular expressions in the "find" dialog, but then it is just like with notepad++, you use the "\n" as the replacement to add the newline.

Sublime text 2 is not free, but it is free to try, and it is cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

With vim, in normal mode,

%s/,/<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>/g